# Error Gmail login OAuth android using webview

Tags: java, android, webview, oauth-2.0, gmail

I tried to log in my app using Gmail log in  Authentication using web view, when i run using emulator always shows the web page is not available.Please find the attached screen shoot.I do not understand how this comes, please any body suggest me how to  get gmail log in authentication and user token.
Thanks in advance
Here is my code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <WebView 
           android:id="@+id/webview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" /> 

</RelativeLayout>

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView webview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

             String OAUTH_URL ="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";
             String REDIRECT_URI="http://localhost";
             String ACCESS_TYPE = "offline";
             String RESPONSE_TYPE = "code";
             String OAUTH_SCOPE="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.google.com/m8/feeds";
             String CLIENT_ID = "";//confidential
            String REQUEST  = OAUTH_URL+"?redirect_uri="+REDIRECT_URI+"&response_type="+RESPONSE_TYPE+"&client_id="+CLIENT_ID+"&scope="+OAUTH_SCOPE+"&access_type="+ACCESS_TYPE;

            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  

                @Override  
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,Bitmap bitmap)  {  

                    System.out.println("onPageStarted url->"+url);
                }
                @Override  
                public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, final String url)  {
                    System.out.println("onPage finished url->"+url);

                    /*if (url.startsWith(Constants.OAUTH2PARAMS.getRederictUri())) {
                        webview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        if (!handled) {
                            new ProcessToken(url,oAuth2Helper).execute();
                        }
                    } else {
                        webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }*/
                }

            });  

            webview.loadUrl(REQUEST);   

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Here iam attaching the screen shot![web page is not avilable]

Answer (score 0):

```
 [Here][1] is a perfect example. 


  [1]: http://tush.wordpress.com/2014/07/15/android-google-contact-api-3-0-example/

Use the authentication process from this example.

And also in your code clientID is blank it can't be empty for debug mode it should 
be empty for only release mode of your application
```